# Массивы Javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
var a = [5, 12];
var b = [];
a[99] = 7;
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  if (a[i] != undefined)
    b.push(Math.pow(a[i], 2));
  console.log(b[i]);
}
for (var i in a) {
  b.push(Math.pow(a[i], 2));
  console.log(b[i]);
}
```

Вопрос: почему в консоли не выводится квадрат 99 элемента?

Comment: **tl;dr:** Потому что `push` пишет не на `i`-ое место.

Comment: @D-side, ответ?

Comment: Как вариант достижения желаемого результата: `b = a.map(function (el) {return el*el});`

Comment: @Yaant, тут на самом деле еще вопрос, какой желаемый результат

Comment: @Grundy, исходя из формулировки вопроса, можно предположить, что ожидается, что `console.log(b[99])` должно вывести число 49. :)

Comment: @Yaant, да, но возможно при этом автор хочет `b.length === 3` :)

Comment: @Grundy В вопросе про это ни слова, а телепатией злоупотреблять нехорошо. :)

Comment: @ Yaant - все верно -  вывести 49

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Потому что вы записываете не то, что считываете.**

`b.push` записывает элемент в "хвост" массива, по индексу `b.length`.

Вы дописываете в `b` элементы только когда натыкаетесь на не-`undefined` элемент в `a`. Поэтому когда цикл натыкается на `undefined` в `a`, величина `b.length` отстаёт на 1 от `i`. А у вас там в массиве `a` довольно внушительная дыра, сквозь которую видно одни `undefined`.

И получается, что число 49 в вашем массиве квадратов находится **под индексом 2, а не 99**, где вы ожидаете его увидеть.

**Что делать?**

Старайтесь соблюдать в коде однородность. Если выводите `b[i]` то записывать есть смысл, как `b[i] = значение`. Или, что может быть даже лучше, сохранять вставляемое значение в локальную переменную и выводить где-то рядом со вставкой.

Comment: _в первом цикле с каждым undefined в a величина b.length отстаёт на единицу от i._ - даже я не сразу понял, что ты тут имел ввиду :)

Comment: _дыра из undefined_ не совсем верно, самих-то элементов нет :) а не куча элементов со значениями undefined

Comment: @Grundy `undefined` это очень странный предмет. Вроде бы есть, но вроде и нет :)

Comment: не-не-не, не надо путать значение undefined, и дырку в массиве :) дырка на то и дырка, что там нет элемента, а не элемент со значением _undefined_

Comment: @Grundy а гарантируется ли это? Что-то мешает JS-реализации реально заполнять дырки `undefined`'ами?

Comment: Ну реализация это такая вещь - кто во что горазд может внутри себя делать :-) надо спецификацию проверить на предмет дырок :)

Comment: Спасибо за подробный и развернутый комментарий

Comment: @Grundy судя по [ответу](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16962031/2076787) в V8 там таки есть элементы со значением `undefined`, т. к. массив меньше 100к элементов. Так что это явно деталь реализации. Но да, в теории ничто не мешает структуре данных не иметь даже места для таких значений и выводить `undefined` при обращении к ним. Только это неважно.

Comment: @D-side, [судя по спецификации](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array-exotic-objects-defineownproperty-p-desc): просто объявляется свойство, то есть добавляется один элемент, а не все промежуточные. В V8, они судя по всему сразу выделяются на всякий случай :)

Comment: @Grundy пока реализация возвращает `undefined` для свойств, которые не были определены, всё ок :) А что реализации приходится для этого делать, уже неважно. Тут ещё, правда, некоторое веселье со свойствами vs. элементами массива, но это уже совсем другая история... а правило на неопределённые элементы массива всё равно тоже действует.

Comment: не не :-) _undefined для свойств, которые не были определены_ - это не значит, что это свойство равно _undefined_ :)

Comment: @Grundy [is that so? (ой ли?)](http://i.imgur.com/zVupwDH.png)

Comment: Ёпрст, что я вообще тут забыл, я ж вообще JavaScript не знаю!

Comment: @D-side, вот что называется плохой тест :-D для проверки наличия свойства нужно пользоваться `hasOwnProperty`, а в твоем случае ты проверяешь что функция получения свойства вернула _undefined_ что ничего не говорит о наличии либо отсутствии свойства :)

Comment: @Grundy и тем не менее, значение, возвращаемое при обращении к этому свойству, таки равно `undefined`, есть это свойство на самом деле или нет, уже вторично :) Я выше уже говорил, `undefined` это очень странный предмет.

Answer (score 4):

Т.к. метод `push()` добавляет элементы и присваивает последовательные индексы, то индексы элементов в `b` будут `0, 1, 2`, тогда как в `а` индексы элементов `0, 1, 99`, поэтому  индексация в массивах `а` и `b` будет отличаться

```js
var a = [5, 12];
var b = [];
a[99] = 7;
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  if (a[i] != undefined) {
    b.push(Math.pow(a[i], 2));
    console.log(b[b.length - 1]);
  }
}
for (var i in a) {
  b.push(Math.pow(a[i], 2));
  console.log(b[b.length - 1]);
}
```

Comment: а почему она отличается? :)

Comment: @Grundy - поддерживаю вопрос: почему отличается индексация?

Comment: @Proshka дополнил ответ